# HTML Forms Data Write To Local File

Tags: javascript, html

Why is error
I don't see test.txt why

thx for helping

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="test(this)" class="form-horizontal" style="font-weight:bold; text-color:black">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">name surname:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="joe">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="test(this)" value="ok" style="font-weight:bold; padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;" class="btn btn-blue big-btn"></label>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(form){
        set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
        set s   = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\test.txt", True);

        var aq = document.getElementById("name");

        s.writeline("[+] Name:" + aq );     
        s.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript. You appear to be mixing VBA with JavaScript.

Comment: [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) is a VBA construct. Can you elaborate a bit as to why you believe this API would be available in JavaScript?

Comment: Generally speaking for this kind of question, it's helpful to include the actual error you're seeing. Can you provide the stack trace from the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scripting.FileSystemObject` is a non-standard API that most browsers don't provide access to under any circumstances. (Internet Explorer might in HTA applications).

You're also trying to use Visual Basic syntax in a script marked as JavaScript. Again, only IE supported client-side VB Script, and you need to use the appropriate `language` flag on the `<script>` element to get it to work.

Generally, the only way to write to a file from browser-side JavaScript is to generate a `data:` scheme URL and navigate to it allowing the browser's default download handling routines to save it (which means you can't control where the data is written to).

Comment: how can i write data to file with js in the my server

Comment: @byNefr3t — See the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Just curios to know, if the javascript can write files to c:/ or as a matter of fact any drive on our hard drive, isn't that  a security issue ? FYI - I don't know anything about HTA.

Comment: @MukeshKeshu — Again, see the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: how can i create a file in the server not client side with js

Comment: Depends on your server side environment. Pick a programming language and apply the use of Google to it.

Comment: with JS javascript

Comment: JavaScript has no native API for writing files. It depends on the host environment to provide it with one. So the answer would be different for Node.js, Classic ASP, and so on. Try using Google.